# help with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

this is my goal **numbers from the three digits to 9 digits**. for example

```
Valid options

175
1.250
14.365
145.985
1.562.745
17.487.984
999.999.999
```

Now this is the regular expression that i develop

```
/^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/
```

My problem it's that this is accepting this values

```
176.57.117 <---- this is not valid value
176.257.7 <---- this is not valid value
176.257.17 <---- this is not valid value
```

Thanks for your help

**UPDATE**
 I'm trying to make a regular expression that validates **positive natural numbers** from **three digits to 9 digits** and separates the **thousand unit and the million unit** with a point

Comment: Your examples make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I think he means anything in the range `100 - 999.999.999`.

Comment: Why is 999.999.999 valid, but not 176.257.17 or 176.257.7 or  176.257.17?  You haven't sufficiently described the validity rules.

Comment: @pimvd: then why is 176.57.117 not valid? that falls within the range.

Comment: @Marc B: I guess the format is not correct - you'd write it as `17.657.117`.

Comment: ah. euro formatting. could be...

Comment: O_o srsly people, this does not need to be closed! It was very clearly put forth and explained.

Comment: i don't think that my question is not a real question, maybe it can be more specific but rather to vote for not a real question is something different

Comment: @Jorge - It's bad form when people ask you to clarify your question and you are silent.  If you fail to clarify an unclear question, people will vote to close it as unanswerable.  Remember, it's only what is unclear to the readers that matters here.  It may seem clear to you, but that isn't the point.  It's whether it's clear to other people who read the question and have none of your other context.  Plus an unclear question is of little lasting value to StackOverflow as a knowledge base as future readers won't necessarily understand what was being asked.

Comment: well, i tried to modify my question and be more specific, and made a specific explanation about what is the valid option. But i don't know why it's not clear, maybe if you explain me which part you don't understand, maybe i can clarified more

Comment: @Jorge, I asked a specific question 44 minutes ago in a comment which you never answered.  Also, people following comments will NOT know about edits unless you add a comment that says you edited your question.  We don't reread your original question every few minutes so we don't know anything changed unless you comment to say you updated the question.

Comment: OK, now almost an hour later and a lot of wasted time, I get it.  Your question doesn't state this, but through all the other comments, I've finally pieced this together.  These are numbers and the decimal point is a separator between thousands and millions so all groups of numbers except the left-most must be three digits long.  I had no idea those were thousands separators.  I live in a part of the world where a period is a decimal point, not a thousands separator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/^\d{1,3}(\.\d{3}(\.\d{3})?)?$/
```

What you really want is 1 to 3 digits possibly followed by 1 or 2 additional sets of three digits.  Your original reg-ex just said "3 sets of 1-3 digits" which isn't really what you want.  It also would have failed to accept your first several valid examples since they had less than three sets of digits.

Comment: Odd.  OP accepted your answer, but never explained what the acceptance rules actually are.  I guess SO has turned into a contest to see who can "guess" what the OP actually meant and the OP feels no need to clarify their question when people ask.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think it's probably because the acceptance rules are fairly obvious from the example when you keep in mind that many European countries us a period to separate digits in a number rather than commas.  So if you imagine his valid/invalid examples as having commas rather than periods, I think that the pattern is pretty clear.

Comment: Based on votes to close his question, it's obviously not clear to everyone.  You apparently made a correct guess, but his specification is severely lacking and he did not respond when people asked him to clarify.

Comment: @jfriend00, he did eventually clarify, he was just slow to do it.  And I know that it wasn't obvious to everyone.  That's why I used qualifiers like "if" and "when" above.  It's clear that not everyone saw the pattern he was going for.

Comment: Keith, I don't mean to be taking this out on you.  I'm just amazed at how horrible so many of the SO questions are.  It's like people have lost their ability to communicate a question clearly.  This was an 8 on a scale of 10 (pretty decent actually) with helpful examples, but still missing a clear description that these were numbers and the decimal points were thousands and millions separators (not something obvious to someone in my part of the world) and didn't answer specific questions asked.  These look more like IP addresses to me than what the OP meant them to be.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string for `.` and then check string length ... in each of array indexes (i think it will be more self explaining than regexp)

Comment: What if one of the characters is not numeric?

Comment: there is always function is numeric ...